# Error code -2 when installing gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to install Gulp using Node.js on OSX but something goes wrong. Here's what i do.

- I installed node.js
- use `sudo npm init` to create `package.json` file
- use `sudo npm install —save-dev gulp`

At this point there was the error.

```
npm WARN package.json dependencies@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json dependencies@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json dependencies@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/dorinocanciani/Sites/prova/resources/dependencies/—save-dev
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "—save-dev" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /Users/dorinocanciani/Sites/prova/resources/dependencies/—save-dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/dorinocanciani/Sites/prova/resources/dependencies/—save-dev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dorinocanciani/Sites/prova/resources/dependencies/npm-debug.log
```

I searched a lot in google but with no results for this type of error.
Please can you help me to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `-` in the command it should be: `npm install --save-dev gulp`

UPDATE: It seems like you are not using the `-` at all but this `—` that's another character and is wrong.